# TypeError: trying to access 'property' on undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm stuck on a strange error: when trying to display a state variable, vuejs warns me:
Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined"

My state looks like this (in the vuejs extension):

```
room:Object
    details:Object
        game_id:"1"
        id:914527404
        max_users:5
        messages:Array[0]
        token:"ef6464692f4cce187fe129d7"
        user:Array[1]
    messages:Array[0]
    users:Array[1]
```

Despite the error, the HTML is still rendered correctly:

```
<button id="copySharingLink" type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" v-bind:data-token="room.details.token">some text</button>
```

becomes

```
<button id="copySharingLink" type="button" data-token="ef6464692f4cce187fe129d7" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">some text</button>
```

I have no idea how to rid out of this error, since it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a time when `room` or `room.details` is not yet set, and that may be when the error is getting thrown.

Try changing the code from this...

```
v-bind:data-token="room.details.token"
```

...to this:

```
v-bind:data-token="room.hasOwnProperty('details') ? room.details.token : ''"
```